# Is there a way to dig deeper into a AWS Cloudwatch error for where "Access Denied" is failing

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I am working on a snippet of code that interacts with an API call to my AWS instance for cognito, it runs the following snippet:

```
public function getCognitoIDPSettings(LoggerInterface $logger, string $cognitoCustomerUserpoolIDP): array
{
    $body = json_encode([
        'cognito_customer_user_pool_idp_id' => $cognitoCustomerUserpoolIDP,
    ]);

    $url = COGNITO_API_INVOKE_URL . '/idp/get';

    $response = $this->postFunction($logger, $url, $body, 'application/json');

    $this->checkResponseStatus($response);

    $body = json_decode($response->getContent(), true);
    if (JSON_ERROR_NONE !== json_last_error()) {
        throw new JsonException("failed decoding response from cognito api");
    }

    return $body;
}
```

When it is hitting the:

```
$response = $this->postFunction($logger, $url, $body, 'application/json');
```

It is erroring with:

```
Error: "Got an error from API: \u0027{\u0022message\u0022: \u0022Internal server error\u0022}\u0027 with error code 0"
File: /var/www/billing/src/Domain/Auth/CognitoAPIFacade.php
Line: 398
```

This error isn't very indicative so I jumped into the Cloudwatch and found:
[image]

I can see it's an "Access Denied" error but I want to dig deeper into where this is occurring or if there's a way I can best further diagnose this, any ideas of people facing a similar problem and can provide some useful guidance?

Answer (score 1):

AWS has a large tutorial on how to [troubleshoot](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/troubleshoot-iam-permission-errors/) Access Denied errors. Basically: Check CloudTrail.

My assumption would be that your lambda is just lacking the correct IAM permissions to access the resource.

Answer (score 0):

The resolution for this was that it wasn't actually an access denied issue, it was masqueraded as I was passing the incorrect ID, it's an AWS security layer to return as an Access Denied rather than an Incorrect ID.

If AWS was to return a Incorrect ID error it enables brute force attacks to be  more effective.